# Cases: how do I include the header of the email if case is email-to-case by outlook

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

**Setup:**

When a user does email-to-case the created by field is an automated case user.

**Questions:**

1. How do I detect if it was by outlook?
2. I need to get the orignal sender. I am trying to get the header of the email but I cannot get it for Outlook... Any ideas on how to get the original sender's email or how to get the header?

Thanks-
El Noobre

Answer (score 0):

With email to case you're pretty limited, and direct access to the header isn't possible.  But you can get around this if you create your own [inbound email handler](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_classes_email_inbound.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_classes_email_inbound.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp), which has methods to access the headers.  If you google around a bit you can find some [good tutorials](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/12/writing-an-inbound-email-service-for-salesforce-com/).